# pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required error

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

Everything else in my code runs, but I receive this error when I try to knit the document: "Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available)." How do I fix this?

Tried to find pandoc_available function, tried closing and opening R again

Comment: Try [installing the latest  version of pandoc](https://pandoc.org/installing.html).

Comment: You need to install Pandoc, or make it visible to rmarkdown if you already have it.  One way to install it is to install RStudio; then while you are in RStudio it will be visible.  But that's not the only way; for more details you need to explain your OS and how you are running R.